# Is it possible to have different paths on the same devise model with constraints?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, constraints

I'm trying to have different paths for the same devise model/resource with constraints, but the first path is the one being applied in this case "visitor".

```
constraints(ValidSubdomainFrontend) do
    devise_for :users, :path => "visitor", :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :password => 'secret', :confirmation => 'verification', :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'register', :sign_up => 'cmon_let_me_in' }
end


constraints(ValidSubdomainAdmin) do
    devise_for :users do
        get 'users', :path => "admin", :to => 'site_backend#index', :as => :user_root # Rails 3
    end
    devise_for :users, :controllers  => { :registrations => 'users' }, :path => "admin", :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :password => 'secret', :confirmation => 'verification', :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'register', :sign_up => 'cmon_let_me_in' }
end
```

Is it possible to have different paths for the same resource with Devise on different constraints?

The constraints being used are:

```
class ValidSubdomainAdmin
  def self.matches?(request)
        request.subdomain.present? && 
        request.env['PATH_INFO'].start_with?('/admin')
  end
end

class ValidSubdomainFrontend
  def self.matches?(request)
        request.subdomain.present? && 
        !request.env['PATH_INFO'].start_with?('/admin')
  end
end
```

Is this possible with Devise at all or is this a Bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution for this issue!

More on the context, basically needed to have something like /visitor on the front-end where users can login (to the members area) and edit their profile and other members/clients operations. But I would also want /admin where admins/editors/authors can login to the (backend) admin dashboard/area. Both areas use the same Devise model/resource (so an admin can also visit the members area). As a side note, currently I'm using CanCan permissions to prevent members from accessing the admin area.

I just had to replace the admin area constraint for:

```
constraints(ValidSubdomainAdmin) do
    devise_scope :user do
      #root :to => "devise/registrations#new"
      get "admin/" => "admin#index"
      post 'admin/' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_admin_registration 
      match 'admin/', :to => 'admin#index'    
      get "admin/edit" => "devise/registrations#edit"
      match 'admin/edit', :to => 'devise/registrations#edit'   
      get "admin/login" => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :new_admin_session
      match 'admin/login', :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
      get "admin/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => 'destroy_admin_session'
      match 'admin/logout', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy' 
      post   "admin/password" => "devise/passwords#create"
      get    "admin/password/new" => "devise/passwords#new", :as => 'new_admin_password'
      get    "admin/password/edit" => "devise/passwords#edit" 
      put    "admin/password" => "devise/passwords#update"   
    end
end
```

I also updated the views /admin/users (being used by devise on the on the admin area) to use the new admin devise paths.

**Many thanks to [José Valim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588267/jose-valim)**